# Angular split string json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm studing angular js, and i create a simple app for test.
I have a json file like:

```
{  
 "result":[  
  {  
     "id":"1",
     "content":"lorem ipsum",
     "files":"file1,file2,file3"
  },
  {  
     "id":"2",
     "content":"lorem ipsum dolor",
     "files":"file4, file5, file6"
  }
 ]
}
```

how I split `files` and make a loop with files in each object? each file# I need to place in `<img>` tag.

Thanks!

*edited

Comment: Is this some pseudo notation you're showing...? Because that's nowhere near JSON. If it was actual JSON and `files` would properly be an array, there wouldn't be any need to "split" anything...

Comment: Use any one of the online json validators to validate your data first. Then provide valid data in question. Question makes no sense as it is now

Comment: it's just a example.

Comment: It's not an example that anyone here can help with. Example needs to be valid javascript for anyone to understand what problem you have

Comment: Make them an array to start with and use `ng-repeat` and `ng-src`

Comment: So how about using `"files": ["file1", "file2", "file3"]` like a sane person?

Answer (score 0):

If you define your object like this:

```
var object1 = {
  user: 1,
  content: "lorem ipsum",
  files: "file1, file2, file3"
}
```

Then what you can do is:

```
var filesArray = object1.files.split(',');
```

and you will end up with an array containing your files.

To iterate through the files you can use a for loop:

```
for (var i in filesArray) {
  console.log(filesArray[i]);
}
```

Also, don't forget you are preserving the leading spaces.
You can remove them with trim():

```
console.log(filesArray[0]) // will print " file1"
console.log(filesArray[0].trim()); // will print "file1"
```

Comment: Sorry, just saw the update. I can change my object definition to reflect your data structure. It should be easily understandable anyway.